# Reactive Extensions on mono?

Tags: c#, mono, system.reactive

this year old question found some issues -

[Is the Reactive Framework (RX) available for use in Mono yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677755/is-the-reactive-framework-rx-available-for-use-in-mono-yet)

Does anyone have current experiences with Rx ?

Comment: Can you explain how you use Rx on mono?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Rx works on Mono great, I have a version of [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net) running on an iPhone and it works quite well. You can find binaries for Rx for Android and iOS [here](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/tree/rxui5-master/ext).

One thing that is important is that you use the very latest version of Xamarin Studio (i.e. the "Alpha Channel" updates), especially on iOS because of the Generics AOT fixes.

Comment: Is there a document somewhere that describes how to get Rx working with Mono (what those hacks are).

Comment: @RobertOschler Just updated this, there aren't really any hacks needed anymore, just grab the appropriate binaries for your platform